# ajax request with php responses in sequence, not in array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

Hi guys here is what I'm trying to do, this is a registration form and first I'm doing a check to see if the username is available, if it is it them proceeds with the registration.
In case the username is available i wanted to give the user feedback, that the name is available and it's proceeded with registration, the issue is, i do the ajax request but the responses come back together not one and then the other, is there a way i could do it for responses to come one and then the other, below is the code:
*Note: both php and js files are external

JS file

```
$.ajax({
    url: "register.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({username: nameToCheck, password: userPass, email: userEmail}),
    async: true,
    beforeSend: ajaxStartName,
    success: nameVerify,
    error: ajaxErrorName,
    complete: function() {
        //do something          
    }
});

function nameVerify(data){
    console.log('ajax data: '+data); // this gives both responses, not one then the other

    if(data == 'nameAvailable'){
        //user feedback, "name is available, proceeding with registration"
    }
    else if(data == 'registrationComplete'){
        //user feedback, "registration is complete thank you"
    {
    else if(data == 'nameInUse'){
        //user feedback, "name is in use, please select another…"
    }
}
```

php file

```
<?php
// the connection and db selection here
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];

if($total == 1){
echo 'nameInUse';
disconnectDb();
die();
 }
 else{  
echo 'nameAvailable';
 register(); //proceed with registration here
 }

 function register(){
 $password= $_POST['password'];//and all other details would be gathered here and sent
 //registration happens here, then if successful
//i placed a for loop here, to simulate the time it would take for reg process, to no avail
//the echoes always go at same time, is there a way around this?
echo 'registrationComplete';    
}

?>
```

I found a few questions that where similar to mine, but not exactly and could not find a definite  answer, so I'm posting my question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot process data in steps (not in this way at least) as JQuery will fire you function only upon your php script finishing working (socket closing).

Use [json](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

```
$res - array('name_available' => false, 'registration_complete' => false);
... some code ...
if (...) {
    ...
} else {
    $res['name_available'] = true;
    ...
    if (...) {
        $res['registration_complete'] = true;
    }
}
...
echo json_encode($res);
```

Then in nameVerify

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
if (data['name_available']) {
    ...
    if (data['registration_complete']) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, so i guess it's not possible due to the (socket closing). Couse even with the way u suggested i could not pass the 'name_available' response first then the 'registration_complete' after completion?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i was able to get this to work was to send a second request

code sample

```
//first request
function nameVerify(data){
console.log('ajax data: '+data); // this gives both responses, not one then the other

if(data == 'nameAvailable'){
    //user feedback, "name is available, proceeding with registration"
    *** here after getting the first response, i send a 2nd request,and place the handlers only 'sharing' the error msgs
    confirmation(); //second request
}
else if(data == 'registrationComplete'){
    //user feedback, "registration is complete thank you"
{
else if(data == 'nameInUse'){
    //user feedback, "name is in use, please select another…"
}
```

I hope it helps someone